# How to harvest/produce industrial amounts of metallic hydrogen

Tags: spaceships, fuels

For those not versed in theoretical states of matter, [Metallic Hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_hydrogen) is a semi-fluid phase of hydrogen that acts like a metal, able to conduct electrons. It's also theorized to be potent rocket fuel. Metallic hydrogen probably naturally occurs within the inner layers of Jupiter and Saturn. You need high heat and/or high pressure to get metallic hydrogen from standard hydrogen.

In my Sci-fi universe, metallic hydrogen is used in Human SSTO shuttlecraft for its low-radioactivity, theoretical isp of 1700, and relatively simple ingredients; but the main problem I'm having is mass production or harvesting.

For one, which would be more economical/logistically feasible, extraction from Saturn/Jupiter/a similar exoplanet or artificial synthesis?

**Please note:** Humanity at this point in history (700 years from the year 2020) has commercialized Fusion Reactors/direct fusion drive systems, FTL drives scavenged and copied from an alien wreck, advanced biotech, mind uploading, hyper-advanced non-sapient AI, and are working on large-scale antimatter production which is a whole 'nother can of worms

**Please Note 2:** I am asking for the logistics and economics of each way of obtaining Metallic Hydrogen, not the how

Comment: Note/question for clarity: I could be wrong, but it sounds like you might be expecting metallic hydrogen to *stay* metallic after the high pressure has been removed. Is that correct? Were you hoping to be shipping around tons of metallic hydrogen without keeping under gigantic pressure? Because I don't think that would work; I suspect it would revert to gas as soon as the pressure is gone. Hopefully someone more certain about it than I can confirm/refute...

Comment: @Qami nah, just handwaving it for now (also I heard from somewhere that it's theorized that metallic hydrogen will stay metallic)

Comment: If you've got easy fusion rockets and fusion reactors, then there's not necessarily a whole lot of point in using metallic hydrogen rocket because nuclear electric propulsion will generally be better because the fuel and reaction mass are easier to come by. Metallic hydrogen that remains metallic at low pressures may be metastable, which is a hazardous sort of thing to have lying around... 50 times more bang than TNT for the same weight, and potentially easy to detonate...

Comment: @StarfishPrime because direct fusion produces a lot of Gamma and X-ray radiation, which isn't too good if your ship is taking off around anywhere with human life, Mettalic hydrogen engines are just take-off/landing thrusters or near stations

Comment: Hydrogen turns metal around 400 GPa. It stops being metallic below that pressure, no question. If you have a container that can store 400GPa hydrogen, then you can put gaseous hydrogen into the container and it will become metallic. Going down into the depths of a gas giant is unnecessary extra effort. Is this the information you're looking for?

Comment: @L-Dutch, I don't believe this is a dupe. The one you link to asks how you would mine metallic hydrogen. This one asks if there is even a point to mining it, and that's a step in the right direction.

Comment: @redfrogcrab that’s why I very specifically mentioned “nuclear electric propulsion”. Metastable super explosive is not a good thing to have where tire worried about human life.

Comment: @StarfishPrime true, but on further research, a funny quirk of Electric propulsion is, the thrust is always going to be insufficient for take-off because if you scale up your power source, you then have to carry the extra weight of the reactor, thus the tyranny of the Rocket equation prevents electric propulsion from being viable for anything with a decent gravity well.

Comment: @redfrogcrab there is nothing intrinsically low trust about electric propulsion.

Comment: @StarfishPrime compared to pure thermal systems, electric systems are pretty intrinsically lower-thrust. Generating and manipulating electrical power always involves losses and additional equipment mass, if you're generating it from a thermal source you're dumping a lot of the power as waste heat. Electrical propulsion is a compromise that allows increasing specific impulse, and that means increasing power requirements for the same thrust (or decreasing thrust for the same power output).

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff i don’t recall saying it had to be a thermal power source either. Honestly, people are happy to accept FTL and super intelligent AI and mining the cores of gas giants, but direct power conversion from a fusion reactor? No, that’s a suspension of disbelief too far, apparently. My bad.

Comment: I didn't say it had to be a thermal power source, I only addressed that as one possibility.

Comment: @StarfishPrime have you never played Kerbal space program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that metallic hydrogen is meta-stable (as indicated in comments) and as the technology level of this civilization is largely unknown, will make many estimates and (probably bad) assumptions to arrive at an answer. With these assumptions, it appears best to mine the hydrogen, but as they could be off by more than the difference between the methods, it is plausible that either method would be more economical.

**Mining the Hydrogen**

Metallic hydrogen is found under about [12,000km of non-metallic liquids](https://astronomy.com/magazine/ask-astro/2018/06/metallic-hydrogen-in-gas-giants) in Jupiter. Obtaining it would require either some sort of pipeline that reaches down to this layer or for some sort of vehicle to dive underneath the liquid layer and mine it. In either case, the main problem will be cooling, but I will assume that the civilization has solved this problem. A pipeline, if feasible, will be more efficient, so as an upper estimate of cost, the hydrogen will have to be mined by single use vehicle, which might cost as much as the most expensive vehicles we make today. These are probably mars rovers, with price tags in the single-digit billions. If a mining vehicle cost about that much, and could bring back about a ton of metallic hydrogen, metallic hydrogen would cost about $1000/gram, which is an upper estimate for the cost of hydrogen via mining.

**Lab Grown Hydrogen**

It is impossible to know the exact economics of producing metallic hydrogen in a lab. However, presumably, the process would be similar to that used to create artificial diamonds, but with much higher pressures. The similarity of these processes means that making artificial metallic hydrogen might cost as much as making artificial diamonds does today, [about $10,000/gram](https://www.diamonds.pro/education/lab-created-diamonds-prices-value/).

Additionally, if metallic hydrogen is meta-stable, it might be possible to grow an existing piece by putting it in some suitable, hydrogen rich environment, like how artificial diamonds can be formed today with chemical vapor deposition. Because artificial diamonds are produced like that today, this yields the same estimation of $10,000/gram.

Comment: Notably, the lab is much closer and much safer than Jupiter, which facts will make themselves felt in the market.

Comment: @Tom I agree, but these are very rough estimates. Taking that into account would be implying too much precision (and isn't part of the price of mars rovers that mars is far from earth and dangerous?).

Comment: the only problem with harvesting I see is how to get a pipeline that can both suck up metallic hydrogen and keep itself in the air (balloons won't work and humans don't have BS anti-grav tech yet). Scooper ships might work and may also get some Deuterium in the process (potent fusion fuel) Right Now I'm favoring artificial synthesis